# Default credential change with the Looker Studio Linking API?

Tags: looker-studio

We have a number of Looker Studio reports that get installed into various client accounts using the Linking API. The main data source is set to use Owner's Credentials in the master report, and has always installed using Owner's Credentials as well. Yesterday, I noticed that it is now being installed with Viewer's Credentials. I know I can change the Credentials during the install process, but would expect it would install the same way it was built. Has something changed? Is there a way for us to make it install the same way it was built?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

noticed exactly the same thing - it's intensely annoying, as nothing was announced regarding this change of functionality.

Prior to the change, we copied reports using the Linking URL, just as you did.  Our reports have 10+ data sources, so it's a total pain to change each one in turn, per copied report.

I have searched high and low to see if there's a parameter option in the Linking URL to allow one to determine how the source permissions are copied over, but to no avail.

One assumes that Google changed this to force the 'safest' data access permissions on copy, but to not provide a facility to set via Linking URL means they have completely hobbled the benefit of this copy method.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: This not an answer, it is sharing the same concern. Please leave it as a comment.